# No such file or directory cygwin + rsyc

Tags: command-line, terminal, cygwin, rsync, openssh

I am trying to send a file in cygwin commandline with rsync and openssh.
So the command I'm using is  `rsync -P -e "ssh -p 2222" deborahtrez@209.6.204.90:/home/dell/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Videos/Movavi/installation_tutorial.mp4`

Then it asks for my password, which I enter. I press ENTER and I always get returned `No such file or directory`
The file path to my video "installation_tutorial.mp4" is in `C:\Users\dell\Videos\Movavi` so the full path becomes `C:\Users\dell\Videos\Movavi\installation_tutorial.mp4`. So this is what I have tried so far.

[image]

Please, what am I doing wrong? Is it my file path? If so, what is the correct file path that i should be using? Help!

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong. The best way to convert from Windows to Posix is to use `cygpath`

```
$ cygpath -u 'C:\Users\dell\Videos\Movavi\installation_tutorial.mp4'
/cygdrive/c/Users/dell/Videos/Movavi/installation_tutorial.mp4
```